# I gave negative margin and the parent div gave more width but the picture can't in the right way

Tags: html, css

[it works, I increase the parent box's width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEIE.png)

But the last picture still not raise .

I want the picture in the same row
[See the image that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyf1k.png)

Here are my HTML code.

```
<div class="main-show">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="./images/pic_1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pic_2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pic_3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pic_4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pic_5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS Code

```
.main-show{
    width: 100%;
}
.main-show ul{
    margin-right: -25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.main-show li{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.main-show img{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit hard to follow. What's the desired outcome?

Comment: I am not good at English.I want the picture displayed on the same line.Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate a proper width for the `li` elements, in your case reduce the `20%` by the `5px` margin:

```
width: calc(20% - 5px);
```

Sidenote: You don't need the float on the `img` as you are already floating the `li` elements.

Update: If you want to remove the last right margin, you should use the selector `li:last-child` and set the `margin-right: 0;`. Now you have to use `width: calc(20% - 4px);` because of the missing last 5px.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.main-show {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.main-show ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main-show li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(20% - 4px);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.main-show li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.main-show img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-show">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the last picture still has the gap(margin-right:5px), I want all the pictures full of the screen's width. I update the question, and you can find what I want to do . thanks!

Comment: If I didn't give the img `float` , it would have the gap like `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

To fit the div in the same row just decrease the width of li tag

```
.main-show li {
float: left;
width: 19%;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-right:-25px;` on `.main-show ul`, and use `width: calc(20% - 5px);` on `.main-show li` to set the width.

That way you'll get an accurate accounting for width.